# How can I send an object to the server on form submit without ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an application that is written on the top of `ASP.NET MVC 5` framework. For one page, I am using this awesome [jQuery-QueryBuilder](http://querybuilder.js.org/) plugin to let the user create filters to narrow down the results of the dataset.

When the user submits the form "by clicking the submit button" I want to call a function `builder.queryBuilder('getRules')` provided by [jQuery-QueryBuilder](http://querybuilder.js.org/) which returns and object that needs to be sent to the server. I don't want the request to be sent as string. Also I don't want to sent it as `ajax` request.

Here is what I have done. The following code is not working. When the server receives the request the rules are always null.

```
$('#submit-form').click(function (event) {

    event.preventDefault();
    var btn = $(this);
    var rules = builder.queryBuilder('getRules');

    if (!$.isEmptyObject(rules)) {
        $('#QueryBuilder_Rules').val(rules);
        btn.closest('form').submit();
    }
});
```

I tried to use `AJAX` to send the post request to the server like the code below shows. The code below worked fine. However, I don't want to use AJAX, I want to do the same thing using regular form post request

```
$('#submit-form').click(function (event) {

    event.preventDefault();
    var btn = $(this);
    var rules = builder.queryBuilder('getRules');

    if (!$.isEmptyObject(rules)) {

        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: url,
          data: {Rules: rules}
        });
    }

});
```

How can I correctly send the `rules` object as an object not a string to the server using standard post request?

Comment: You can create a temporal form using js to create a normal post request or just use async: false and your ajax function will work similarly to an actual post but of course the browser will have to support xhr

Comment: @slowdeath007 I tried to creating temporary form as you suggested. But the data that is being sent is still string not object.

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem in using Ajax?

You may consider doing the following:

```
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",                     
       url: url,                                                 
       data: JSON.stringify({Rules: rules}),           
       dataType: "json",
       contentType: "application/json",
       success: function (json) {

       }

[HTTPPost]
public void Rules(YourClass[] array){...}
```

Comment: I don't want to submit Ajax. + your converting the object to string. did you read my question?

Comment: Hi Jaylen, I red your question indeed! and because its not possible to accomplish what you are asking for I suggested to you in do as I'm showing in the example....